# How do I assign R/S configuration?

Tags: nomenclature, chirality

[image]

So I have this molecule shown up here and I need to give its systematic name according to the UIPAC and need to give its R/S configuration in the name. I suspect the name to be 3-tert-butyl-2-methylheptan-4-one but I don't know the R/S thing however.

Comment: This answer may give you some insight on the rules for assigning R or S. http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/23988/402

Which group has the highest priority? Why?

Comment: Ok but where is my asymmetric carbon? Would it be at 3?

Comment: then it would be (3S)-3-tert-butyl-2-methylheptan-4-one ?

Comment: Yes, this would be correct.